# Sublime Text 3 Console - NameError: name 'npm' is not defined

Tags: console, command, sublimetext3

Can't you use the sublime text console for commands? like "grunt" or "npm install"?

I can trigger the commands from cmd but I would like to do it direct from sublimetext

I've jumped from phpstorm to sublime text for a better user interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot. The console interface is to Sublime's built-in Python interpreter, it's not a shell.

Comment: Thanks that answered my question, now I'm looking for a plugin that could do the job